# Relation between a filter and its complement being an ideal.

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, filters

**Exercise.** Show that a true filter $\mathcal{F}$ in $X$ is an ultrafilter **iff** the complement of $\mathcal{F}$ is an ideal, i.e., $Y,Z \notin \mathcal{F} \Leftrightarrow Y \cup Z \notin \mathcal{F}$, for $Y,Z \subset X$.

**My resolution.**

$(\Rightarrow)$ Suppose $\mathcal{F}$ is an ultrafilter in $X$. Then, $\mathcal{F}$ is also a prime filter on $X$, i.e.,
\begin{equation*}
\forall \hspace{.15cm}Y,Z \subset X, \hspace{.25cm} Y \cup Z \in \mathcal{F} \Rightarrow Y \in \mathcal{F} \text{ or }Z \in \mathcal{F}.
\end{equation*}
Directly from the property above (i.e., the definition of a prime filter) we have that $Y,Z \notin \mathcal{F} \Rightarrow Y \cup Z \notin \mathcal{F}$. Thus all we want to prove now is that $Y \cup Z \notin \mathcal{F} \Rightarrow Y,Z \notin \mathcal{F}$. Let us assume now that $Y \cup Z \notin \mathcal{F}$ but $Y \in \mathcal{F}$ or $Z \in \mathcal{F}$. WLOG, assume that $Y \in \mathcal{F}$. So, $Y \subseteq Y \cup Z \Rightarrow Y \cup Z \in \mathcal{F}$, which is a contracdition, proving what we wanted.

$(\Leftarrow)$ Suppose now that the complement of $\mathcal{F}$ is an ideal, i.e., $Y,Z \notin \mathcal{F} \Leftrightarrow Y \cup Z \notin \mathcal{F}$, for $Y,Z \subset X$. So it's trivial that $\mathcal{F}$ is a prime filter just by applying $(p \Rightarrow q) \Leftrightarrow (\lnot q \Rightarrow \lnot p)$, and if $\mathcal{F}$ is a prime filter in $X$, then it is also an ultrafilter.

Well, I just wanted to check if what I made is correct. To me, its makes plenty of sense but at the same time I feel like I made it way too simple. Thanks for all the help in advance.

Comment: Do you know that prime filters are ultrafilters too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that argument works provided you know the *equivalence*

$$\mathcal{F} \text{ is an ultrafilter on } X \iff \forall F,G \subseteq X: (F \cup G \in \mathcal{F}) \to (F \in \mathcal{F} \lor G \in \mathcal{F})\tag{1}$$

(where ultrafilter is defined as inclusion-maximal filter on $X$).

If $(1)$ is an established fact (in *both* directions; you only claim the direction left to right to be known to you) then the right hand statement is indeed the same as

$$\forall F,G \subseteq X: (F \notin \mathcal{F} \land G \notin \mathcal{F}) \to (F \cup G \notin \mathcal{F})\tag{2}$$ by modus tollens and de Morgan. And logical equivalence is transitive..

Comment: So all I nedeed to prove is that every ultrafilter is also a prime filter? Thanks for your Help!

Comment: @Seabourn no, that every prime filter is an ultrafilter.

Comment: Wouldn't that only show one implication of the equivalence wanted? i.e., \begin{equation*} Y,Z \notin \mathcal{F} \Leftrightarrow Y \cup Z \notin \mathcal{F} \end{equation*}

Comment: @Seabourn that’s my statement $(2)$ which is by pure  propositional logic equivalent to the RHS of $(1)$ and *then* you need to know that a prime filter is an ultrafilter to prove the final part of the equivalence.

Comment: Ok, I think I got it! Thanks for the help!